# nested list in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am not sure if this is a stupid question, but I was doing some simple problems on lists in F#. I am unable to handle nested lists. My question is, Why I can't pass a nested list when I have declared a list as parameter of a function? I mean the nested list is also a list. What is the advantage of differentiating lists of simple int or char from lists of lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function is generic and takes a parameter `'a list`, the type of `'a` could also be a list. So the function would work with lists, or lists of lists, or lists of lists of lists, ...so long as the outer type is a list, `'a` could be anything.

For example:

```
let isNonEmpty = function
    | [] -> false
    | _::_ -> true

isNonEmpty [1; 2; 3]
isNonEmpty [[1]; [2]; [3]]
```

If your function doesn't depend on the list elements being of a certain type it should probably be generic. If you post your code perhaps someone can help with that.

#### EDIT

A naive version of your `flatten` function, without using built-in functions, might be:

```
let flatten lst =
    let rec helper = function
        | [] -> []
        | h::tl ->
            match h with
            | Elem x -> x::helper tl
            | List xs -> helper xs @ helper tl
    helper [lst]
```

Comment: The task is to write a function that flattens a nested list structure. And for that I need a new data type whose definition is already given in the problem. I am trying to write the code using pattern matching and without using any built-in function for lists like List.Fold etc

Comment: type 'a NestedList = List of 'a NestedList list | Elem of 'a      
> flatten (Elem 5);;
val it : int list = [5]       
> flatten (List [Elem 1; List [Elem 2; List [Elem 3; Elem 4]; Elem 5]]);;         
val it : int list = [1;2;3;4;5]

Comment: Here is my code which is not working yet
`code` 

let flatten (lst: 'a NestedList) =                                                                                              
    let rec helper lst1 lst2 =                                                                                                       
        match lst1 with                                                                                             
       |Elem x -> lst2 @ [x]
       |List [List x ; List xs]-> lst2 @ [x] @ helper (List xs)
       |List a :: Elem b-> lst2 @ [a] @ (helper b)
    helper lst [];;

Comment: @AnmolYousaf: I updated my answer with an example implementation.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I desire to experience more about the design of F#. What is the purpose of having a homogeneous list? Unlike F#, in scheme lists are non homogeneous. Which one is more powerful to implement the ideas of functional programming.

Comment: I think that is not so much an issue of functional programming but of static vs dynamic typing. Personally, I prefer static typing for most things, but a thorough comparison of type systems is a pretty deep subject...and resources abound on the subject.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a function requiring a `list<char>` and you have a `list<list<char>>` those types don't match. However, there is a function [List.concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370370.aspx) which will "flatten" the list of lists.

So:

```
let list = [ ['a'] ; ['b'] ]
let list' = list |> List.concat  // [ 'a' ; 'b' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for more of a dynamically typed nested list behavior, you should take a look at my NestedPair module:

https://gist.github.com/calebh/45871d3d40dc93526b3fd227cd577467

This module allows for "lists" of arbitrary depth by using a simple wrapper type.